# how to import an existing django project to pycharm

Tags: python, django, pycharm

I have the following directory tree

```
myproject
├── data
├── libs
└── wsgi
    ├── openshift
    └── static
```

openshift contains the settings file  and the manage.py file. I want to user manage.py through pycharm but it won't work, nor the runserver command nor the startapp neither anything to be precice.

running startapp gives me the following errors

```
bash -cl "/usr/bin/python2.7 manage.py startapp quiz"
/usr/bin/python2.7: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Process finished with exit code 2
```

running runserver it gives me the following

```
ImportError: Could not import settings 'openshift.settings' (Is it on sys.path? Is there an import error in the settings file?): No module named openshift.settings

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I have enabled django support and set wsig as django root project. Running manage.py from terminal works fine.

what am i doing wrong?

EDIT: running manage.py shell from pycharm also works
EDIT2: I managed to get it working by following openshift's structure and making openshift the django project root folder, and some edits to the imports. Now everything works great

Answer (score 17):

Open myproject as your project and then go to PyCharm -> Preferences... -> Django, Enable Django Support and then choose your Django project root, settings file and manage script.

Comment: Do you have a virtual environment for your project? Is Django installed?

Comment: No to virtual enviornment and yes to Django install

Answer (score 3):

just open pycharm and in file menu select open option.
Then choose your directory and done..!

If you have problem with using command line then you should try building a new project from pycharm itself.

Comment: You have to enable django support and not only open the directory within pycharm. I know I can build it from scratch using pycharm but I don't. I get my folder from openshift git repo.

Comment: okay understand and i think you need more expert answer. sorry. tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

PyCharm 2022.3.1 (Professional Edition)

Once you opened your project in PyCharm:

File -> Settings -> Languages & Frameworks -> Django -> Enable Django Support

1. Set "Django project root" to your project's main folder.
2. Point "Settings" to where the settings.py file is.
3. Point "Manage script" to where the manage.py file is.
4. "Folder pattern to track files" is set to "migrations" on new projects.

Before you apply the settings "Show structure" will be empty. It will get populated once you applay the settings and try opening it again.

Answer (score 0):

I usually change the run configuration's working directory option.

You could type your working directory path into that field, then python will find the project's settings module